# How to use a resizable rounded rectangle as KeyIcon

Tags: android, xml, drawable, android-softkeyboard

I'm working on an android keyboard application. As you know key object can set an icon or label for itself , so now I wanna set a re-sizable rounded rectangle for space keyboard button like [This one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BV4a1.jpg)

I wanna make it able to be resized when it's running on large screens , I have this in my keyboard xml class :

```
<Key android:codes="46" android:keyIcon = "@drawable/space_button_drawable.xml">
```

what should I have in my space_button_drawable.xml ?

**EDIT 1 :**

buttonbgselector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button" />
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button2" />
</selector>
```

keyboard.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/keyboard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:keyBackground="@drawable/buttonbgselector"
    android:keyPreviewLayout ="@layout/preview" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

space_button_drawable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:radius="10dp" />
    <solid
        android:color="#AAA" />
</shape>
```

use this drawable in your background of LinearLayout keyboard.xml

Comment: @Maquz Thanks for answer , but I have set an image as keys background , I cant change that one , How can I change background of JUST ONE KEY ?

Comment: mmm i dont know... but this article can help u http://tutorials-android.blogspot.cl/2011/06/create-your-own-custom-keyboard-for.html

Comment: Maybe I have to create another buttonbgselector.xml for space key and set space key background selector to it , wait I'm going to test it